# Rails ransack predicate escape character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ransack

Is there any way to tell ransack which escape character to use?

I created a custom predicate to let the user use asterisk as a wildcard character (instead of %). What this does is to replace any asterisk in the search term with a percent sign.

To let the user search after percent-signs, i want them to be escaped in the search query (except for the actual wildcard asterisks).

As an example i got a user named "us%er_name". Searching for "us%er_na*" should return this user. For this, the query should look like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'us\%er\_na%' escape '\';
```

The escaping and replacement works fine but i don't know how to get "escape '\'" in the query.

A generic solution would be preferred as i don't want to do anything other than to just use my custom predicate.

-e-

In short:

I want to escape a users search term and supply the escape character to the query to get a query like the following when searching after "user%name":

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'user\%name' escape '\';
```

Comment: You should go for regular expression `Arel.sql(
    "regexp_replace(
      to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"id\", '9999999'), ' ', '', 'g')"
  )`

Comment: I don't think you understood my question as i don't understand what you're trying to say ;) -e- did you realy just copy an example from https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers ? This isn't even close to my question

Comment: then explain what you want to achieve here ?

Comment: I updated the question.